# Mysql high cpu usage - cpanel

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, configuration

After an update from `whm`, I see a high CPU usage from MySQL (5.6).
`my.cfg`:

```
[mysqld]
slow_query_log=1
slow_query_log_file="/var/lib/mysql/slow-query.log"
long_query_time=1
skip_name_resolve
myisam_use_mmap=1
log_queries_not_using_indexes=1

max_connections=500
max_user_connections = 150

#safe-show-database

query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_size = 75M
query_cache_limit = 20M

join_buffer_size=3M
read_rnd_buffer_size=1M
read_buffer_size = 4M
max_allowed_packet=268435456

tmp_table_size=25M
max_heap_table_size=25M

table_open_cache = 7500
thread_cache_size = 50

open_files_limit=30000

key_buffer_size = 500M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 134217728
innodb_log_file_size = 64M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M

#default-storage-engine=MyISAM
```

Server Specs:

```
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU 930 @ 2.80GHz 
RAM: 6.2 GB
```

Top:

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
2206 mysql    20   0 3266m 295m  27m S 247.0  4.8   6249:25 mysqld
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

EDIT: the server is up for 7 days
Process list:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0  10372   524 ?        Ss   Jun30   0:01 init [3]
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jun30   0:00 [kthreadd/101]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jun30   0:00 [khelper/101]
root       480  0.0  0.0   5932   524 ?        Ss   Jun30   0:05 syslogd -m 0
root       483  0.0  0.0   3828   408 ?        Ss   Jun30   0:00 klogd -x
dbus      1714  0.0  0.0  21284   380 ?        Ss   Jun30   0:00 dbus-daemon --system
root      1742  0.0  0.0 212980  4000 ?        Ss   Jun30   1:27 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
named     1755  0.0  0.0 338312  2820 ?        Ssl  Jun30   0:18 /usr/sbin/named -u named
root      1777  0.0  0.0  64816   576 ?        Ss   Jun30   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd
root      1788  0.0  0.0  21664   524 ?        Ss   Jun30   0:00 xinetd -stayalive -pidfile /var/run/xinetd.pid
root      1802  0.0  0.0  10788   504 ?        S    Jun30   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/cpanel.*****.**.pid
mysql     2206  124  4.3 3345320 275076 ?      Sl   Jun30 6259:14 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/cpanel.*****.**.err --open-files-lim
root      2622  0.0  0.0  93396   752 ?        Ss   Jun30   0:00 pure-ftpd (SERVER)
root      2624  0.0  0.0  35924   720 ?        S    Jun30   0:00 /usr/sbin/pure-authd -s /var/run/ftpd.sock -r /usr/local/cpanel/bin/pureauth
root      2632  0.0  0.0  19728   596 ?        Ss   Jun30   0:01 crond
root      2646  0.0  0.0  18752   404 ?        Ss   Jun30   0:00 /usr/sbin/atd
root      2762  0.0  0.0 138188  3944 ?        S    Jun30   0:06 cpsrvd (SSL) - waiting f --llu=1435642525 --listen=3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
root      2866  0.0  0.0  18712   228 ?        S    Jun30   0:00 /usr/sbin/smartd -q never
root      2870  0.0  0.0   3812   360 ?        Ss+  Jun30   0:00 /sbin/mingetty console
root      2871  0.0  0.0   3812   360 tty2     Ss+  Jun30   0:00 /sbin/mingetty tty2
root      3902  0.0  0.2 162088 16844 ?        S    09:54   0:12 spamd child
root      3980  0.0  0.0  79344  2784 ?        S    18:07   0:00 /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/perl /usr/local/cpanel/bin/leechprotect
root      8554  0.0  0.0  69152  2720 ?        SNs  03:00   0:00 /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/cpbackup
root     13922  0.0  0.0  92332  2940 ?        Ss   20:03   0:00 sshd: root@notty
root     13960  0.0  0.0  56068  2068 ?        Ss   20:03   0:00 /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
denissan 13990  0.0  0.1 214608  8780 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14007  0.0  0.1 214604  8384 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14008  0.0  0.1 214604  8324 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14009  0.0  0.1 214604  8412 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14010  0.1  0.1 214604  8504 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14011  0.0  0.1 214604  8384 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14012  0.0  0.1 214604  8384 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14013  0.1  0.1 214604  8580 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14014  0.0  0.1 214604  8408 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14015  0.0  0.1 214604  8336 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14016  0.0  0.1 214604  8324 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14017  0.0  0.1 214604  8344 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14018  0.0  0.1 214604  8464 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14019  0.0  0.1 214604  8444 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14020  0.0  0.1 214604  8368 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14021  0.0  0.1 214604  8412 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14022  0.0  0.1 214604  8448 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14023  0.0  0.1 214604  8396 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14024  0.1  0.1 214604  8424 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14027  0.1  0.1 214604  8676 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14028  0.0  0.1 214604  8432 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14029  0.0  0.1 214604  8372 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14030  0.0  0.1 214604  8404 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14031  0.3  0.1 217612 11688 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14032  0.0  0.1 214604  8432 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14033  0.0  0.1 214604  8608 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14034  0.1  0.1 214604  8460 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14035  0.0  0.1 214604  8388 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14036  0.1  0.1 214604  8496 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14039  0.0  0.1 214604  8564 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14040  0.0  0.1 214604  8400 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14041  0.0  0.1 214388  8284 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14044  0.0  0.1 214604  8232 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14045  0.0  0.1 214604  8216 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14046  0.1  0.1 214428  8180 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14047  0.0  0.1 214604  8288 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14048  0.0  0.1 214604  8456 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14049  0.0  0.1 214604  8276 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14050  0.0  0.1 214388  8428 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14052  0.0  0.1 214428  8372 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14053  0.0  0.1 214604  8292 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14054  0.0  0.1 214612  8276 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14055  0.0  0.1 214604  8448 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14056  0.0  0.1 214604  8400 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14057  0.0  0.1 214388  8256 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14058  0.0  0.1 214604  8348 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14059  0.0  0.1 214612  8320 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14060  0.0  0.1 214604  8472 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14061  0.0  0.1 214636  8656 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14062  0.0  0.1 214604  8392 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14063  0.0  0.1 214604  8324 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14064  0.0  0.1 214604  8252 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14065  0.0  0.1 214604  8424 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14066  0.0  0.1 214604  8632 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14071  0.0  0.1 214604  8272 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14072  0.0  0.1 214604  8584 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14073  0.1  0.1 214604  8688 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14074  0.0  0.1 214604  8372 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14081  0.0  0.1 214388  8276 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14082  0.1  0.1 214604  8468 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14083  0.0  0.1 214604  8316 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14084  0.0  0.1 214604  8224 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14085  0.0  0.1 214604  8100 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14086  0.0  0.1 214604  8456 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14087  0.1  0.1 214604  8284 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14088  0.0  0.1 214604  8464 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14089  0.0  0.1 214388  8292 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14090  0.0  0.1 214612  8496 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14091  0.1  0.1 214604  8468 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14094  0.0  0.1 214604  8260 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14095  0.1  0.1 214596  8276 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14096  0.0  0.1 214604  8028 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14098  0.0  0.1 214604  8412 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14099  0.1  0.1 214604  8420 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14100  0.0  0.1 214604  8424 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14101  0.0  0.1 214604  8436 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14102  0.0  0.1 214604  8468 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14103  0.1  0.1 214612  8328 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14104  0.0  0.1 214604  8412 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14105  0.0  0.1 214620  8272 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14106  0.1  0.1 214596  8576 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14107  0.0  0.1 214604  8276 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14108  0.0  0.1 214604  8312 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14109  0.0  0.1 214604  8304 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14110  0.1  0.1 214604  8344 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14111  0.0  0.1 214604  8368 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14112  0.1  0.1 214604  8448 ?        S    20:03   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14149  0.0  0.1 214604  8380 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14151  0.0  0.1 214604  8300 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14152  0.0  0.1 214604  8368 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14156  0.0  0.1 214604  8320 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14157  0.0  0.1 214604  8388 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14158  0.0  0.1 214604  8256 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14159  0.0  0.1 214604  8404 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14163  0.0  0.1 214352  8224 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14164  0.1  0.1 214604  8464 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14165  0.0  0.1 214352  8268 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14166  0.0  0.1 214352  8284 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14167  0.0  0.1 214352  8224 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14168  0.0  0.1 214352  8236 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14170  0.0  0.1 214352  8268 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14171  0.0  0.1 214352  8264 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14179  0.0  0.1 214352  8212 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14180  0.0  0.1 214352  8220 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14181  0.0  0.1 214352  8216 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14182  0.1  0.1 214604  8260 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14184  0.0  0.1 214352  8220 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14185  0.0  0.1 214352  8224 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14186  0.0  0.1 214352  8268 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14188  0.0  0.1 214352  8224 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14189  0.0  0.1 214604  8272 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14190  0.0  0.1 214388  8276 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14191  0.0  0.1 214352  8224 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14192  0.0  0.1 214604  8712 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14193  0.0  0.1 214604  8296 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14194  0.0  0.1 214352  8272 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14197  0.0  0.1 214604  8248 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14198  0.0  0.1 214604  8452 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14211  0.0  0.1 214604  8252 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14212  0.0  0.1 214352  8268 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14213  0.0  0.1 214604  8412 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14214  0.0  0.1 214604  8248 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14215  0.0  0.1 214604  8264 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14216  0.0  0.1 214352  8224 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14217  0.0  0.1 214604  8456 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14218  0.0  0.1 214352  8240 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14219  0.0  0.1 214352  8280 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14220  0.0  0.1 214352  8228 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14221  0.0  0.1 214388  8276 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14222  0.0  0.1 214352  8224 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14223  0.0  0.1 214604  8356 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14224  0.0  0.1 214352  8228 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14225  0.0  0.1 214352  8244 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14226  0.0  0.1 214352  8228 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14227  0.0  0.1 214352  8272 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14229  0.0  0.1 214352  8228 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14230  0.0  0.1 214604  8388 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14231  0.0  0.1 214604  8416 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14232  0.0  0.1 214352  8272 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14233  0.0  0.1 214604  8256 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14234  0.0  0.1 214348  8320 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14235  0.0  0.1 214352  8272 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14236  0.0  0.1 214352  8240 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14237  0.0  0.1 214352  8224 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14238  0.0  0.1 214352  8240 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14239  0.0  0.1 214352  8224 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14240  0.0  0.1 214604  8456 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14241  0.0  0.1 214352  8272 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14242  0.0  0.1 214352  8240 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
denissan 14276  0.0  0.1 214604  8408 ?        S    20:04   0:00 /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd -DSSL
root     14477  0.0  0.0   3804   472 ?        SN   20:04   0:00 /usr/local/cpanel/bin/cpuwatch 6.0 /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/pkgacct vdc /backup/cpbackup/daily backup --nocompress
root     14478  5.9  1.0 183704 64076 ?        SNs  20:04   0:01 pkgacct - vdc - av: 3
vdc      14668  0.9  0.9 183704 61052 ?        DN   20:04   0:00 pkgacct - vdc - av: 3
root     14676  0.0  0.0  10480   928 pts/0    R+   20:04   0:00 ps aux
root     26030  0.0  0.0  17464   856 ?        Ss   Jul01   0:12 /usr/sbin/dovecot
dovenull 26032  0.0  0.0  43524  2196 ?        S    Jul01   0:30 dovecot/pop3-login
dovenull 26033  0.0  0.0  43308  1864 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 dovecot/imap-login
dovecot  26034  0.0  0.0  13128  1008 ?        S    Jul01   0:06 dovecot/anvil
root     26035  0.0  0.0  13380  1104 ?        S    Jul01   0:08 dovecot/log
dovenull 26037  0.0  0.0  43472  2196 ?        S    Jul01   2:08 dovecot/pop3-login
root     26038  0.0  0.0  16216  1744 ?        S    Jul01   0:13 dovecot/config
dovenull 26039  0.0  0.0  43332  1980 ?        S    Jul01   0:00 dovecot/imap-login
root     26095  0.0  0.0 385532   772 ?        Ssl  Jul01   0:39 /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/clamd
mailnull 26102  0.0  0.0  69880   724 ?        Ss   Jul01   0:01 /usr/sbin/exim -bd -q60m -oP /var/spool/exim/exim-daemon.pid
root     26168  0.0  0.0 161152  4076 ?        Ss   Jul01   0:27 /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/514/bin/spamd --daemonize --max-spare=1 --max-children=3 --allowed-ips=127.0.0.1 --pidfile=/var/run/spamd.pid -i127.0.0.1
root     27471  0.0  0.0  38284  2428 ?        S    Jul01   0:05 queueprocd - wait to process a task
root     27492  0.0  0.0  87012  5052 ?        S    Jul01   0:55 tailwatchd
root     27572  0.0  0.0  36448  3096 ?        S    Jul01   0:17 cPhulkd - processor
root     27602  0.0  0.0  29408   740 ?        SN   Jul01   0:00 cpanellogd - sleeping for logs
root     30707  0.0  0.0  92472  1912 ?        Ss   19:32   0:00 sshd: root@notty
root     30712  0.0  0.0  56200  1492 ?        Ss   19:32   0:00 /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
root     30784  0.0  0.0  92332  1896 ?        Ss   19:32   0:00 sshd: root@pts/0
root     30789  0.0  0.0  10920  1304 pts/0    Ss   19:32   0:00 -bash
root     32058  0.0  0.0  54856  5400 ?        Ss   00:00   0:32 lfd - sleeping
```

the user denissan is a torrent tracker and is spamming with it's announce but it was doing it before whm decided to update and i had no problems with pages loading slow

Comment: Why, is anything wrong?

Comment: loading a page takes forever and %cpu is 247.0

Comment: Turn off the query_cache (query_cache_type). Set your innob_buffer_pool_instaces to 4. Why is your key_buffer_size 500M? How long has it been (has the db had time to warm up)? Post your processlist and lets see whats going on.

Comment: i edited the question

Comment: Ah sorry the mysql processlist. Check the contents of your slow logs, find out whats running slow. Is 128M large enough of a buffer pool for mysql? Why is the key_buffer_size 500M? Are you using many myisam tables?

Comment: yes they are alot, i have alot of slow queries but i cannot do anything about that as the people that i host cannot change their structure/logic,

Answer (score 0):

Check for high traffic users using MyISAM or ARIA table engine. I run CloudLinux cpanel boxes and even with CPU throttling a single high volume user with lots of writes to MyISAM table can lock the whole server up.